# How do I get my certificate to self sign using CA

Tags: node.js, ssl, openssl, child-process

I'm new to the OpenSSL and Node community and could use some help on some commands.

I'm working on a node application where users can input their information and get a browser certificate to hit an application I have on my server. I want the user to be able to put in their information once, then have a browser cert download (in other words, all the commands need to run with no more user input).

I have the three commands using [child processes in Node](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) and [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/) and I'm trying to translate them over to node, but I'm having some issues.

My first command get variables from the users runs fine:

```
sudo openssl req -new -nodes -out /etc/pki/tls/request/bdd-req.pem -keyout /etc/pki/tls/private/bdd-key.pem -subj "/C='+country+'/ST='+state+'/L='+locality+'/O='+organization+'/CN='+name+'" -passout pass:'+password+' -x509 -days 365 -config /etc/pki/tls/openssl.cnf
```

However when the second command runs, I get an error:

```
sudo openssl ca -out /etc/pki/tls/cert-pem/bdd-cert.pem -days 365 -config /etc/pki/tls/openssl.cnf -passin pass:*PASSWORD* -keyfile /etc/pki/tls/private/cakey.pem -cert /etc/pki/tls/cacert.pem -selfsign -infiles /etc/pki/tls/request/bdd-req.pem


Error: Command failed: Using configuration from /etc/pki/tls/openssl.cnf
Error reading certificate request in /etc/pki/tls/mapedit-req-pem/bdd-req.pem
140052424636320:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:703:Expecting: CERTIFICATE REQUEST

at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:658:15)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
at maybeClose (child_process.js:766:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:833:5)
```

What is the `CERTIFICATE REQUEST` it's asking for? Isn't that the `cert` flag?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand how this isn't a development question. I'm asking a question [similar to this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175812/how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate-with-openssl) about how to work with OpenSSL in Node. Am I missing something?

Comment: The controlling or dominating part of the question is how to use the `openssl ca` subcommand (unless I am missing something, which could well be the case). You are right about the cited question - its off-topic too. Unfortunately, Stack overflow does a rather poor job at policing itself.